# How to call super in an init method with nil terminated list of params?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am subclasing UIAlertView. I would like to implement a init method with the following signature:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
            message:(NSString *)message
         identifier:(NSInteger)ident
           delegate:(id)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles,...
```

It is just the default UIAlertView method with an added param `identifier`.

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
            message:(NSString *)message
           delegate:(id)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles,...
```

What is the correct syntax now to invoke the super method if I don't know in compile time what my init method `otherButtonTitles` params will be?

```
self = [super initWithTitle:title
                    message:message
                   delegate:delegate
          cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle 
          otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];
//I will only get the first param with this syntax
```

Comment: This isn't possible. See [Subclassing UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309869/subclassing-uialertview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Learn about **variadic functions**, it can help you: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)

```
Example:
#include <stdarg.h>

void logObjects(id firstObject, ...) // <-- there is always at least one arg, "nil", so this is valid, even for "empty" list
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, firstObject);
  id obj;
  for (obj = firstObject; obj != nil; obj = va_arg(args, id)) // we assume that all arguments are objects
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Second, it's better to make an **Objectve-C Category** rather than subclass UIAlertView

```
Example:
@interface UIAlertView(Identifiers)
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
            message:(NSString *)message
         identifier:(NSInteger)ident
           delegate:(id)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles,...;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say

> **Subclassing Notes**
>   The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

But to the point I don't think you can. You could always just recreate this convenience method  by implementing a normal `init` and then configuring the object with the arguments passed in.